# mysql error mysqli_real_connect()

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site that started receiving an error when I hit the homepage.  The error is:

Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. in D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1538

I was able to get it back up after I created a new db and restored from backup but after a few minutes I started getting the error again.  The site is hosted in Azure and the mysql db is hosting cleardb.  Any help you can provide as to why I am getting this error would be helpful.  I have updated Wordpress to the latest version and updated php to version 7 but that did not fix the error. Any body point me in the right direction?

Comment: That's the error, which is helpful. Do you know what line of code generated that? Stack Overflow is highly focused on coding issues, so if you're not prepared to dig in and debug it, this is a WordPress tech support problem that doesn't fit here.

Comment: The line of code is:

Comment: The line of code is: 

mysqli_real_connect( $this->dbh, $host, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, null, $port, $socket, $client_flags );

I currently don't have any client flags.  this is the standard WordPress wp-dp.php file.